# how to run PPC Leopard on an Intel Mac for QA Purposes?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, powerpc

Our QA needs to test our software on PPC Leopard. Is there a way to do that w/o buying some old PPC HW?

Oren

Comment: I just so happen to have some old PowerPC hardware. :-) Where are you located? (Sorry, I'm sure this is all kinds of inappropriate. To get back on topic, I suggest checking your local [craigslist.org](http://craigslist.org) for some cheap used test machines if you decide you need to go that route.)

Comment: @Cody: And I know some people who are looking for old PowerPC hardware!

Comment: Apparently you might have some luck with qemu...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming your OS is Leopard then you just need to make sure you have Rosetta installed and PowerPC executables will run transparently under PowerPC emulation.

Comment: This will work for executables compiled for PowerPC processors. However, I believe the question is asking about running a version of OS X itself compiled for PowerPC processors on an Intel Mac, which is not possible.

Comment: @Cody Gray: ah - I see the ambiguity now - thanks. If that *is* the case then the OP does need to buy an old PowerPC Mac.